# Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for a Riemann sum limit

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm trying to use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma which states that for any integrate function $f\in L^1[a,b]$,
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{a}^bf(x)\exp(ixk)dx=0,
$$
to prove that
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j)\exp(i x_j/\Delta x_j)\Delta x_j=0
$$
where $a<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_N<b$ is a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ in $N$ points and $\Delta x_j=x_{j+1}-x_j$. Since for $N\to\infty$, $\Delta x_j\to 0$, the result almost follows from the Riemann sum, but the key point is that in the second equation the limit which approaches the Riemann sum to the integral is same that takes the imaginary exponent to infinity.

**EDIT:** After comments pointing that the above limit does not exist, as it depends on the partition, I am reformulating the problem to be more specific in the limiting procedure. Assume $x_1=a$, $x_N=b$ and $\Delta x= (b-a)/N$, the question is then to prove that
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j)\exp(i x_j/\Delta x)\Delta x=0.
$$
This kind of limits appear in statistical physics when taking the thermodynamic limit, then $N$ represents the physical volume.

Comment: I would guess that the statement is not true in general. Maybe we can pick $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$. We can try to simplify our life by forcing $x_j/\Delta x_j \in 2\pi \mathbb{N}$, in that case, we would get that our "Riemann sum" converges to $1$ (we are just summing up the $\Delta x_j$). So the question is whether we can pick $x_j$ in such a way and also respect the condition that we can make $\Delta x_j$ as small as we like. We have $$2\pi n_j= \frac{x_j}{\Delta x_j} = \frac{x_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j}.$$ Hence, we get $$x_{j+1}=\frac{1+2\pi n_j}{2\pi n_j}x_j.$$

Comment: If we wish to make $\Delta x_j \leq \delta$, then we need to ensure that $$\delta \geq \Delta x_j =\frac{x_j}{2\pi n_j}.$$ As $x_j\in [0,1]$, we are good to go if $n_j\geq \frac{1}{2\pi \delta}.$

Comment: It might be a good idea to spell out my rough idea in an answer. Then we all know whether it is correct and you can also earn some reputation.

Comment: You need to also pick $x_1$ in a good way as we need $x_1-0\leq \delta$. Furthermore, the computation for $\Delta x_N$ only holds true if $\frac{1+2\pi n_N}{2\pi n_N} x_N =1.$ To simplify the choices, we can pick $n_j=n$ (i.e. independent of $j$). Then we get $$x_j = \left( \frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n}\right)^{j-1} x_1.$$ So, we get $$x_1= \left( \frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n}\right)^{-N}.$$ We saw above that $n=\lceil \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \rceil$ is a possible choice. So we now pick $N$ sufficiently large, such that $$\delta \geq \left( \frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n}\right)^{-N}=x_1.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your comments are interesting! It seems the limit may not exist properly, because apparently you can remove any oscillation by an appropriate choice of the partition. However, I guess we can make a similar reasoning by splinting the interval $[0,1]=[0,1/2]\cup[1/2,1]$ and adjust the exponents in such a way that are $2\pi \mathbb{N}$ in $[0,1/2]$ and $2\pi \mathbb{N}+\pi$ in $[1/2,1]$ to get a final $1/2-1/2=0$ result. Then I would be interested in which conditions ensure the result...

Comment: Surely you can find partitions in this case that give you zero as a limit (and otherwise where the limit does not exist in the first place). You want to impose conditions on the partitions to make it work? I'd bet that this is in general quite hopeless (as it would depend in a complicated way on the function). My point is that philosophically you are fighting a losing war. If this should be anything like a Riemann sum, then this better be true for any partition.

Comment: It might help the community if you include why you care about the result, respectively, why you believe something like that should be true. It clearly does not follow by naive Riemann sums and I see no reason for something like this to hold true (note that it fails for a constant function).

Comment: I understand and I agree, but let me formulate the limit in a slightly different way. Let us impose $x_1=a$, $x_2=b$, and $\Delta x_i=(b-a)/\lambda$, $\forall j$, in such a way that the freedom to remove the oscillations of $\exp(i x_j/\Delta x)$ is not possible. Then, is it true that $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \sum_j  f(x_j)\exp(i x_j/\Delta x)\Delta x=0$?

Comment: This kind of limits appear in physical context when taking thermodynamic limits (there $\lambda$ represents the physical volume).

Comment: I see. Indeed, I would expect this to be true, but I need a moment to think of a convincing reason.

Comment: I have edited the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: In fact, I am not really sure, whether that works out. It looks like you would at least need more regularity/integrability (i.e. something like $H^1$). Otherwise, consider the function $$ f: (0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \begin{cases} p^2,& x=1/p, p \text{ prime number},\\ 0,& \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$ This function is in $L^1$ (I could also make a smooth version of that requiring that the bumps are only supported on $[1/p, 1/p +1/p^2]$). Then your limit does not exist (actually it goes to infinity).

Comment: Ok, it is not a problem to assume that $f(x)$ to be continuous, or piecewise continuous, or even differentiable with integrable derivative if needed

Comment: When I say $f(x)$ is "integrable", I mean to say "Riemann integrable", perhaps this is enough (?)

Comment: Indeed, that rules out my previous example as Riemann integrable functions are bounded. Still I don't see how to show your claim. Was a bit too optimistic before.

Comment: One thing that one could try is to regroup the sum in such a way that the phases are opposite to each other. Then you get something that looks like $$ f(x_j) e^{ij} + f(x_{j+K}) e^{i(j+K)} = (f(x_j) - f(x_{j+K})) e^{ij} + f(x_{j+K}) (e^{ij} - e^{i(j+K)}).$$ If $f$ is lipschitz with lipschitz constant $L$, then the first term in absolute value can be bounded by $LK (b-a)/N$ and the second term in absolute value is bounded by $\Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1-e^{iK}\vert$. So we would need to find $K$ such that $\vert 1-e^{iK}\vert=o(1)$, but $K=o(N)$ for $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Actually it should be $e^{ij}+e^{i(j+K)}$ and then $\vert 1+e^{iK}\vert =o(1)$, but that does not change the argument.

Comment: However, $\vert 1+e^{iK}\vert = \vert e^{iK}- e^{i \pi } \vert \leq C \min \{ \vert K - \pi - 2\pi n \vert \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. So we only need to make $K-\pi$ small modulo $2\pi$, which we can in such a way that $K=o(N)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sum up my many comments above into a single answer. For general partitions one can construct counterexamples. However, if one restricts oneself to equidistant partitions and continuous functions, then the OP's statement is indeed true.

**Original question (general partition):**

Let's consider first the original question. There we were allowed to pick any partition and in that case the limit does not tend to zero. The idea is to consider a partition such that $x_j/\Delta x_j \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ and therefore, we are left with

$$ \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{i x_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j = \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) \Delta x_j \rightarrow \int_a^b f(x) dx, \quad \text{as } N \rightarrow \infty. $$

Thus, in general, the limit would not be zero. Let us consider the case $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Then we want to satisfy

$$ \frac{x_j}{\Delta x_j} = 2\pi n, $$

for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that we will choose later. This readily implies

$$ \frac{x_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j} = 2\pi n \Longleftrightarrow  x_{j+1} = \frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n} x_j.$$

This gives us

$$ x_j = \left(\frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n} \right)^{j-1} x_1. $$

Now we have $x_{N+1}=1$ and thus, we get

$$ x_1 = \left(\frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n} \right)^{-N}.$$

Now we need to show that we can choose $n,N$ in such a way that the partition is fine enough. Namely, we want $\max \Delta x_j \leq \delta$. Then we need (for $j\in \{ 1, \dots, N \}$)

$$ \Delta x_j = \frac{x_j}{2\pi n} \leq \delta. $$

As $\vert x_j \vert \leq 1$, we can choose $n= \lceil \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \rceil$. In order to get $\Delta x_0 = x_1 \leq \delta$, we just choose $N$ sufficiently large. A possible choice would be

$$ N = \lceil \frac{\ln(\delta^{-1})}{\ln(\frac{1+2\pi n}{2\pi n})} \rceil.$$

**Refined question:**

Next we are dealing with the refined question. Here we are considering only equidistant partitions and give ourself some more regularity. In this setting we try to see the cancellations "by hand". We are regrouping the sum into pairs that - morally - should cancel each other. In order for this to work, we will assume that $f$ is continuous (with the same argument one could allow for piecewise uniformly continuous $f$ with finitely many discontinuities). In this setting we have

$$ x_j = a+ \frac{b-a}{N} j, \quad \Delta x_j = \frac{b-a}{N}. $$

To make the idea more transparent, we will only consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and so $x_j=\frac{j}{N}, \Delta x_j= \frac{1}{N}$.

Let $K\in \mathbb{N}$ and choose $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2KM \leq N < 2K(M+1)$. We write

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{i j}  \\
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\ell=0}^{M-1}\sum_{j=2K\ell+1}^{2K\ell +K} \left( f(x_j) e^{i j} + f(x_{j+K}) e^{i (j+K)} \right) \\& \quad+ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=2KM +1}^N f(x_j) e^{i j}.
\end{align*}

The last term can be bounded by

$$ \lvert \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=2KM +1}^N f(x_j) e^{i j} \rvert
\leq \frac{2K}{N} \Vert f \Vert_\infty. $$

Next we consider the blocks that we arrange in pairs. For this we notice that

\begin{align*}
&\lvert f(x_j) e^{i j} + f(x_{j+K}) e^{i (j+K)} \rvert \\
&\leq \vert f(x_j)-f(x_{j+K})\vert + \vert f(x_{j+K}) \vert \cdot \vert e^{ij}+e^{i(j+K)}\vert \\
&\leq \left(\sup_{x,y\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert x -y \vert \leq K/N} \vert f(x) -f(y) \vert \right) + \Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert.
\end{align*}

Thus, we get

\begin{align*}
&\lvert \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\ell=0}^{M-1}\sum_{j=2K\ell+1}^{2K\ell +K} \left( f(x_j) e^{i j} + f(x_{j+K}) e^{i (j+K)} \right) \rvert \\
&\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{\ell=0}^{M-1}\sum_{j=2K\ell+1}^{2K\ell +K} \left( \left(\sup_{x,y\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert x -y \vert \leq K/N} \vert f(x) -f(y) \vert \right) + \Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert \right) \\
&= \frac{KM}{N} \left( \left(\sup_{x,y\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert x -y \vert \leq K/N} \vert f(x) -f(y) \vert \right) + \Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert \right) \\
&\leq \left(\sup_{x,y\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert x -y \vert \leq K/N} \vert f(x) -f(y) \vert \right) + \Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert.
\end{align*}

Hence, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\lvert \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert
\leq \left(\sup_{x,y\in [0,1] \ : \ \vert x -y \vert \leq K/N} \vert f(x) -f(y) \vert \right) + \Vert f \Vert_\infty \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert + \frac{2K}{N} \Vert f \Vert_\infty.
\end{align*}

The first and the third term go to zero if we choose $K=o(N)$ (for the first term we use the uniform continuity of $f$ as we are on a compact interval). This leaves us to pick $K$ in such a manner that $\vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert =o(1)$. For this we notice that

$$ \vert 1+ e^{iK} \vert = \vert e^{iK} - e^{i\pi} \vert. $$

Hence, we only need to make sure that $K-\pi$ is small modulo $2\pi$. This is certainly true if we choose $K\in \mathbb{N} \cap [0,\sqrt{N}]$ such that

$$ \min_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \vert K - \pi - 2\pi n \vert $$

is minimized.

To adapt the argument for piecewise uniformly continuous $f$ with $S$ (finite number) discontinuities, one needs to consider the blocks that hit a singularity separately. However, there are at most $2KS$ terms that get affected and so we discard these terms making only an error that is bounded by $2\frac{KS}{N} \Vert f \Vert_\infty$ (again small if $K=o(N)$). To deal with general intervals of the form $[a,b]$, one only needs to replace all factors of $\frac{1}{N}$ by factors of $\frac{b-a}{N}$.

**Update:** In fact, we can also show it for $f$ Riemann integrable (as the OP suggested to begin with). For this we only need a density argument. Let $h: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a step function. In particular, we know that (for equidistant partitions)

\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^N h(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j =0.
\end{align*}

Then we get

\begin{align*}
&\lvert \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert \\
&\leq \lvert \sum_{j=1}^N h(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert + \lvert \sum_{j=1}^N (f(x_j)-h(x_j)) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert \\
&\leq \lvert \sum_{j=1}^N h(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert + \sum_{j=1}^N \vert f(x_j) - h(x_j)\vert \Delta x_j.
\end{align*}

Taking $N \rightarrow \infty$ the first term vanishes and the second one converges to the corresponding Riemann integral (as both $f,h$ are Riemann integrable)

\begin{align*}
 \limsup_{N\rightarrow \infty} \lvert \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert 
\leq \Vert f - h \Vert_{L^1([a,b])}.
\end{align*}

As $f$ is Riemann integrable, we can for every $\varepsilon >0$ find some step function $h_\varepsilon$ such that $\Vert f-h_\varepsilon \Vert_{L^1([a,b])}\leq \varepsilon$ (pick left Riemann sums for $h_\varepsilon$ and go through the construction of the Riemann integral). As the LHS does not depend on $h$, we get

$$ \limsup_{N\rightarrow \infty} \lvert \sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j) e^{ix_j/\Delta x_j} \Delta x_j \rvert =0, $$

which proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work on the detailed answer. However there are few points which do not follow. First, do you really need $N\leq 2K(M+1)K$? Don't you mean to say $N\leq 2K(M+1)$ instead? Secondly, I do not follow the partition of the sum. What do the dots (...) indicate there? how do you get a term "$\ldots+1/N$" without any multiplication by some factor $f(x_j)$? Thirdly, don't you get a $2K$ factor in front of $ (\sup...) $ in the final upper bound (because of the summation $\sum_{2KM-K+1}^{2KM}$). Sorry, probably I missing something simple in the reasoning.

Comment: The first is a typo, the rest are easy manipulations. I am using $\Delta x_j=1/N$. Will make some changes later.

Comment: Ok, now everything should be clear.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expected it to require such elaborated proof...

Comment: At the end of the day it is not that bad. We don't use anything beyond first semester university math :) it is just a bit lengthy. In my experience this is quite typical for questions motivated by physics (the mathematical physics papers tend to be quite long). If there are some spots that you don't understand, please let me know. At the end of the day it is really just picking a phase such that we have cancellation between pairs.

Comment: @NessunDorma I completed the proof to include all Riemann integrable functions. It relies on a simple approximation argument.

Comment: Thank you for this improvement!